# Don't know how to search for a substring within a string

Tags: string, perl, mismatch

I have two sequences:

**a**: `ATGCATGCATGCATGCATGC`

**b**: `GATGATGCATAGCATGCATGTTTGCGATGAATCGC`

I want to search sequence **a** in sequence **b** and give the position where it is matched.

*Output for the above example:* `5`

Comment: Great! What did you try?

Comment: Fuzzy matching? String edit distance?

Answer (score 9):

This answer is based on

> "I want to search sequence a in sequence b and give the position where
>   it is matched."

and not your question title which seems to suggest a different question than actually in your post?

```
my $haystack = 'GATGATGCATAGCATGCATGTTTGCGATGAATCGC';
my $needle = 'ATGCATGCATGCATGCATGC';
my $pos = index($haystack, $needle);
if($pos != -1) {
  ....
}
```

Comment: I think the OP was using Perl, not PHP :-)

Comment: +1 for knowing both. I like how the Perl code is more concise. =)

Answer (score 1):

```
my $a = 'GATGATGCATAGCATGCATGTTTGCGATGAATCGC'; 
my $b = 'ATGCATGCATGCATGCATGC'; 
my $p = index($a, $b) + 1;                      # returns 5
```